# How were Sine tables made during th Middle Ages?

Tags: trigonometry

In previous questions during 2014 Ptolemy's chord method was stated to derive their length from angles. However his method was not described. It just stated the equation in modern terms. I have an extensive background in mathematics and was a professional navigator and surveyor during my career. I am writing a paper about Jewish Astronomers of the Middle Ages. I learned that Rabbi Levi ben Gershom (1288 - 1344) constructed sine tables that were correct to the 5th decimal. He was a mathematician and astronomer and he did work in math on series among other things. Therefore I first assumed he made use of the standard method with infinite series for which he would only have needed 3 terms to get this accuracy, however that method seems to have been developed only after his death. Does anyone have an idea how Rabbi Levi ben Gershom (aka Gersonides) calculated his sine values ?

Comment: Maybe empirically? Making huge circles/triangles and measuring distances.

Comment: @Gershon Welcome to Math SE! While this site is about mathematics, you can post your question at a better site that is more relevant to your question called [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't know how he did it, but you can approximate them by the values at $k\pi/2^n$, which can be computed by halving the angle and addition.

Comment: There's material on ben Gershom in this extraordinary history of trigonometry: The Mathematics of the Heavens and the Earth https://press.princeton.edu/titles/8956.html

Comment: M. Winter: Ptolemy did what you suggest, however I cannot find any info on how he graphically plotted the angles.

Comment: Olsen5: The equation to calculate the sine of an angle is well known. It is sin x =x-(x3 / 3!) +(x5 / 5!) - (x7 / 7!) etc     NB (x3, x5, etc means x to the power 3, 5 etc). Using only 3 terms of this series will provide Gersonides accuracy to 5 decimals when he used the value used for pi back then, being 3.1415.

Comment: Toby Mak & Ethan Bolker: I tried all kinds of books suggested by Google that were not helpful. I'll give your suggestions a go, even if they don't have what I am looking for, the titles sound very interesting to be studied anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my reply to Olsen5 that x in the above equation is in radians.